# Mongodb - Mongoose Mapping relations with populations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models: User and Block. Users can have many blocks and I need a way of mapping those relations between the two models. I came across [populations](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in the mongoose docs and tried to set that up with my schemas:

In `/models/block.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Block',{
  _creator:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
  name:String,
});
```

In `/models/user.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',{
  username:String,
  password:String,
  email:String,
  blocks:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Block'}]
});
```

And when I save a block:

```
router.post('/block/new',function(req,res){
  var block;
  block = new Block({
    name = req.body.name,
    _creator = req.session.user
  });
});
```

...the _creator attribute is not saved to the collection. I can confirm that the block does save. When I go to the console and search for the blocks (`db.blocks.find()`) the new block shows up, but doesn't show any reference to the creator of the block. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going on. The id was being stored in `req.session.user` as a string. I needed to be pulling it from `req.user._id`